# Why ArrayList's non-static inner class SubList has a member variable “parent”?

Tags: java, arraylist, sublist

I have found the same question on [Why ArrayList's non-static inner class SubList has a member variable "parent"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21923674/why-arraylists-non-static-inner-class-sublist-has-a-member-variable-parent) . There was an answer six years ago, but I still have my own confusion. If there isn't "parent" member in SubList, would class SubList work? We can see the source of ArrayList.SubList

```
private class SubList extends AbstractList<E> implements RandomAccess {
    private final AbstractList<E> parent;
    private final int parentOffset;
    private final int offset;
    int size

    SubList(Abstract<E> parent, int offset, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.parentOffset = fromIndex;
        this.offset = offset + fromIndex;
        this.size = toIndex - fromIndex;
        this.modCount = ArrayList.this.modCount;
    }

    public E set(int index, E e) {
        E oldValue = ArrayList.this.elementData(offset + index);
        Array.this.elementData[offset + index] = e;
    }
    public E get(int index) {
        return ArrayList.this.elementData(offset + index);
    }

    public void add(int index, E e) {
        // ArrayList.this.add(parentOffset + index, e); ?
        parent.add(parentOffset + index, e);
        this.modCount = parent.modCount;
        this.size++;
    }

    public E remove(int index) {
        // E result = Array.this.remove(parentOffset + index); ?
        E result = parent.remove(parentOffset + index);
        this.modCount = parent.modCount;
        this.size--;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Can we replace `parent.add`, `parent.remove` with `ArrayList.this.add`, `ArrayList.this.remove`? I think it's ok. So do we need "parent" variable member in class ArrayList.SubList?

Comment: Sublist method get parent with this keyword because each sublist can have a sublist as well.

Comment: Thank's a lot. Yes, `ArrayList.SubList ` has a method `subList` to return a new `SubList(this, offset, fromIndex, toIndx)`. But SubList has not a method to return it's *parent* SubList. All keywords of *parent* in code are used to `add` ore `remove`.  If we don't use **this**, the new SubList object will remain a reference to the backed ArrayList. And we replace `parent.add`, `parent.remove` with `ArrayList.this.add`, `ArrayList.this.remove`. It will work, I think.